# Hide navigation bar in jellybean

Tags: hide, navigationbar

I am working on an Android app which needs full screen mode. I am able to hide action bar and status bar. But able to hide navigation bar temporarily. On touch it will reappear. I found that pm disable com.android.systemui will achieve a truly full screen mode that is what I wanted. But it will restart the system. How to prevent it from restarting.  I want to hide navigation bar only for my app without interfering with other app. I am using api level 17